# Code not executing after page load in Phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm implementing push notification in my Android Phonegap app. When the user clicks the notification, the app opens and then I want to wait until it loads before displaying the message. Here is the code:

```
bindEvents: function() {

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},


onDeviceReady: function() {

    alert('in onDeviceReady');

},


goToMessage: function(){

    alert('in goToMessage');

},


onNotificationGCM: function(e) {

    alert('in the onNotificationGCM');

    switch( e.event )
    {

        case 'message':
           alert('in message');
           document.addEventListener('load', this.goToMessage, false);

            break;

        default:
           // alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
            break;
    }
},
```

onDeviceReady() executes when the app is opened and i see the "in message" alert in the switch statement. But goToMessage() is never executed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd say the document is already loaded at this point, so the listener you added is never executed. Could that be possible?

Comment: yes that's probably it. i've decided to do a redirect instead with window.location.hash